# Find number of consecutive elements that are the same before they change

Tags: python, list

So for example if I have the lists

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2]
b = [1,1,2,2,2]
c = [2,1,1,1,1]
```

I would want to get the longest streak of the first element in the list, so for example `a` would give 3, `b` would give 2 and `c` would give 1. I know I could create a while loop and count the streak that way, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: if you want to count all instance of first element then you can use a.count([0])

Comment: The phrase "longest '*streak*' of the first element" is a bit ambiguous: whether the answer to `[1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1]` is 3 or 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
numStreak = ([a[0] == n for n in a]+[False]).index(False)
```

(this also makes sure that if all elements are like the first element, index does return the correct value)

UPDATE: a more efficient (but less elegant?) version

```
from itertools import takewhile
len([1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x:x==a[0], a)])
```

or a bit better (UPDATE 2) @vaultah's suggestion:

```
sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x:x==a[0], a))
```

Comment: This is very clever but it makes me sad that it iterates over the whole list even if the length is just 1.

Comment: I've added a more efficient but maybe slightly less elegant version

Comment: Should be `sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x:x==a[0], a))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use groupby and sum how many items are in the first group for each:

```
a = [1,1,1,2,2]
b = [1,1,2,2,2]
c = [2,1,1,1,1]

from itertools import groupby

for l in [a,b,c]:
    print(sum( 1  for _ in next(groupby(l), [[], []],)[1]))
```

Or using takewhile:

```
from itertools import takewhile

for l in [a, b, c]:
     print(sum((1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: x == l[0], l))))
```

If your data is always a list, tuple etc.. in the *groupby* you can check for a *falsey* value  as opposed to setting a default in `next(..`:

```
for l in [a, b, c]:
    print(sum(1 for _ in next(groupby(l))[1]) if l else 0)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the `[[], []]` part.  What's it doing?

Comment: @DSM, if an empty iterable  was passed you would get a `StopIteration` error

Comment: Ah, okay, I see what you're up to now.  If we know we have sequences I'd probably just add `if l else 0` at the end, but that wouldn't handle the case of a general iterable.

Comment: This is the better two solutions IMHO

Comment: @DSM, I was going to go with that initially but as you said it would not work in a general case, I added the alternative anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One liner for the road? Take aim...

```
a = [5,5,5,5,8]
list(np.ediff1d(a)).count(0)+1
>>> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1,1,1,2,2]
>>> b = [1,1,2,2,2]
>>> c = [2,1,1,1,1]
>>> def runs(data):
...    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != 0)[0]+1)
... 
>>> for e in a,b,c:
...    runs(np.array(e))
... 
[array([1, 1, 1]), array([2, 2])]
[array([1, 1]), array([2, 2, 2])]
[array([2]), array([1, 1, 1, 1])]
```

Then just take the length of the first run:

```
>>> for e in a,b,c:
...    len(runs(np.array(e))[0])
... 
3
2
1
```

Or, in Python, just use a `while` loop:

```
>>> def r(a):
...    i=1
...    while a[0]==a[i]: i+=1
...    return i
... 
>>> r(a)
3
>>> r(b)
2
>>> r(c)
1
```